# how to edit etc/usb_modswitch.d?

Tags: text-editor

Hello I would like to enter a text file with some code in this directory(etc/usb_modswitch.d). How can I do this? please help me. I have try to do this by just move the file but it's a root directory so I got the message permission denied! So How can I become the root and able to copy paste a file there or is it possible to to do this changes by using terminal?
Thanks.
My os is ubuntu 11.10 version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing /etc/grub.d/40\_custom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674736/editing-etc-grub-d-40-custom)

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> (don't worry, you'll use it only to invoke the text editor with sudo privileges).

On the terminal type:

```
sudo gedit
```

press enter and input your password when prompted.

Presto, the gedit editor should be running with root permissions!