# Editing /etc/grub.d/40_custom

Tags: grub2, kubuntu, live-cd

Are there any available methods so that I can edit my /etc/grub.d/40_custom from a LiveCD or such? I really need to edit that file. Thank you.

Comment: To clarify: You have an Ubuntu installation on hdd that won't boot anymore. The reason is the mentioned grub config file. Your question is how to access the file system on the hdd from a LiveCD. Is that correct?

Comment: Nope, I specifically need to edit a line in that file as I have entered a wrong value there.

Comment: Isn't that pretty much what I asked? In order to edit the file, you need access to the filesystem. Obviously your OS is not booting anymore, because otherwise you could edit the mentioned file the same way you did before. If Grub fails, the way to go is booting from a LiveCD. I won't type out an answer, since there are myriads of tutorials on the subject around, e.g. http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd 
In your case you probably won't need to reinstall Grub, but only update-grub after editing the file. Good luck! Ask back if you need furher help.

Comment: I have already tried it out, also there aren't any mention of editing the mentioned file anywhere in Google. Thank you.

Comment: *"I specifically need to edit a line in that file as I have entered a wrong value there"* > If your only issue is booting on this entry, then simply edit it from the grub boot menu with the 'e' key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Boot a Live System from CD/DVD/USB
2. Assuming the root partition of the Ubuntu installation on the hdd is `sda1`, mount it to `/mnt`

   `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`

   If the root filesystem is not on on `sda1` use e.g `sudo fdisk -l` to find the correct identifier.
3. Open the file `/mnt/etc/grub.d/40_custom` with your favorite editor, e.g

   ```
   sudo nano /mnt/etc/grub.d/40_custom
   ```
4. Make any changes you feel necessary. Best to make a backup beforehand.
5. Now you need to update Grub.

   a. Mount the kernel filesystems to their appropriate places

   ```
       sudo mount --rbind /dev /mnt/dev
       sudo mount --rbind /sys /mnt/sys
       sudo mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
   ```

   b. Do you have a separate boot partition?
     If **yes**, mount it to `/mnt/boot`

   c. Change root to `/mnt`

   ```
       sudo chroot /mnt
   ```

   d. Issue `update-grub`. This will generate a new `grub.cfg` and write it to `/boot/grub/`. (Btw, this is equivalent to `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`)
6. Reboot.

Comment: My old 40_custom is not visible. A new 40_custom is created with read-only permission. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: I followed this - http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd along with the workaround.

Comment: @Raphael I'm not really happy with the edit you made. The fact that you couldn't 'edit the file' has imho nothing to do with `nano`. What was the error? Did the file even exist? If not, was the very first `mount` command successful? I ask because you apparently went on to edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` which is weird, because __before__ the `chroot` this file belongs to the _Live_ filesystem, not the one you mounted (or maybe didn't?) to `/mnt` !

Comment: I edited it after chroot, and also nano couldn't detect the file whereas the file existed when I browsed it through dolphin i.e., after I have mounted sda and changed root. I edited it cause it might have helped somebody else. Oh well!