Ubuntu bootloader superuser loop
I got stuck in a loop that I can't get out of
I have an Ubuntu desktop 24.04 installed on virtual box.
After the installation of superuser in the grub 40_costume file in Ubuntu when I clicked reboot it of course brought me the screen for entering a username and password
After I enter a username and password, it goes to the next screen
But it gets stuck in a loop - no matter what I press it goes back to entering a username and password
I can't get out of this loop - even if I turn the system off and on, it gets stuck there and doesn't go to the normal login.
Tried to press esc or shift key to get to recovery mode as suggested with no luck
I've turned off and in the virtual box system nothing seems to work

perhaps related https://askubuntu.com/questions/674736/editing-etc-grub-d-40-custom

grub 40_costume file? Please give details about exactly how you altered your grub.

@OrganicMarble I've changed the 40_costum file in grub.d directory. Actually just for exercise but I want to understand the error. I've added superuser name and password so that single user mode would not be able to login. But now I'm stuck there and can't login at all to the Ubuntu desktop.  Actually no matter what I click it always comes back to username and password it does not pass that stage... I also wrote down and took a screenshot of what I configured in the file so it seems I'm login in correctly. Hope it's clearer now, thanks
